# iOS add targets to existing application with fastlane

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, fastlane, fastlane-match

I would like to extend an existing application with a production and a test target with more of prod / test target combinations.

The applications are based on the same source code and are configured with different .plist files and config files, so its really just a new target which is needed (along with all the profiles and stuff...)

There is an existing fastlane setup (with environment files .env.App1), but I don't know to which extend this was used to create the app and the portal stuff.

I extended this setup with a new .env.App2 file and added the desired bundle id and started the app creation with

```
fastlane create_app --env App1
```

where lane create_app simply calls

```
create_app_online
```

This worked fine and the application id was created on the apple side.

Now I have a problem with the signing part.

In the project "automatically manage signing" is active.

When calling sync_code_signing for the same environment everything goes fine, but the signing stuff is not solved in xcode for this target unter signing & capabilities.
I have the certificates in the according git repo (this problem was solved in another question, if somebody struggles with that)

How do I solve these 3 errors?

```
Failed to register bundle identifier
The app identifier "com.BUNDLE_ID" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.


Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the Associated Domains and Push Notifications capability.


Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the aps-environment and com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlements.
```

What all these different apps need are

- Associated domains
- Background modes
- Push notifications

So i have a .entitlements file, a .plist file and a target for each app.

How can I find out what the problem is and fix the signing part for all my apps / targets?

thank you